# Unable to connect to firebase admin from Node js server

Tags: node.js, firebase-admin

Am trying to validate a token from by nodejs server. I used the below code.

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('path/to/serviceConfig.json');
    admin.initializeApp({
    projectId: "projectid",
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "databaseurl"
  });
 admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)
        .then(function(decodedToken) {
        console.log("DecodedToken"+ decodedToken);
})
```

i get the below error..

```
FirebaseAppError: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.googleapis.com. Error code: ENOTFOUND
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\Programs\Studies\auth-service-master\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:42:28)
    at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\Programs\Studies\auth-service-master\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:88:28)
    at new FirebaseAppError (C:\Programs\Studies\auth-service-master\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:123:28)
    at C:\Programs\Studies\auth-service-master\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\api-request.js:209:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  errorInfo: {
    code: 'app/network-error',
    message: 'Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.googleapis.com. Error code: ENOTFOUND'
  },
  codePrefix: 'app'
}
```

Am using a free spark plan. Not sure what the issue is here....

Comment: That's a DNS lookup error. You're either offline, or behind a Firewall that's blocking connections to Google services.

Comment: Yes am connecting from my office laptop. Its behind a firewall. Any config file which or something is available as we have for npm so that i can do some changes there?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify proxy settings via an `httpAgent`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.AppOptions#httpagent

You can find a code sample that uses the `https-proxy-agent` package here: https://medium.com/faun/firebase-accessing-firestore-and-firebase-through-a-proxy-server-c6c6029cddb1